# how create new Employee in hybris programmetcally

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am unable to create new user with below code :

```
final EmployeeModel empl=new EmployeeModel();
empl.setUid("test");
modelService.save(empl);
```

Comment: can you please add the error message in order to help you more with this? Thanks!

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Do you really want to create a new 'EmployeeModel' in the code? Than you should use the modelService.create() methode. Or do you want to add a new 'Employee' to the database? than you should create it, for example over the /hmc. So your question is really irritating...

Answer (score 2):

Also, don't do this: `new EmployeeModel();`

You should always use the ModelService to create new instance of ItemModel:

```
modelService.create(EmployeeModel.class)
```

Using `modelService`, it will go through any Interceptor that's define for this type and then, could initialize default value for your item. When your using the `new` operator. It won't set the default value, and can result in the kind of error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

This code works in an hybris out of the box.
You have probably customized the employee type and added mandatory fields.
Check the error detail, you will probably find out the field you missed.